# filehelpers Custom converter

Tags: converters, subclass, filehelpers

I am not sure how the custom converter should be for another `class` that I use as an array within a specific `class`.
Given the following - can someone point me towards the best way for the converter? I am trying to avoid having in the `Team` `class` repeated fields with a number extension to keep them separate if possible.

```
[FixedLengthRecord(FixedMode.AllowMoreChars)]
public class Team
{
    public Team()
    {
        Players = new member[2]{new member(), new member()};
    }
    [FieldFixedLength(60)]
    [FieldConverter(typeof(myMember)]
    public member[] Players;
}

[FixedLengthRecord(FixedMode.AllowMoreChars)]
public class member
{
    [FieldFixedLength(10)]
    public string FirstNameName;

     [FieldFixedLength(10)]
     public string LastName;

     [FieldFixedLength(2)]
     public string Spacer;

     [FieldFixedLength(8)]
     [FieldConverter(typeof(myDate), "MMddyyyy")]
     public DateTime Birthday;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I was thinking more along the lines of a custom converter.  This should work..

```
 internal sealed class SegmentConverter<T> : ConverterBase where T : class
{
    public override string FieldToString(object from)
    {
        T value = (T)from;
        return CommonEngine.WriteString<T>(new[] { value }).TrimEnd('\r', '\n');
    }
    public override object StringToField(string from)
    {
        return CommonEngine.ReadString<T>(from).First();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was pretty sure you just need to decorate a base class with the fixed or delimiter attribute and then inherit from that base class in your member class.  If you then need to also have different records based off the base class read from the same file, you would need to make use of the multi record engine and then use a custom selector to return the type that is desired for importing.

Thus make Member based off Team.